# Show Product Name in Laravel Model Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Can you help me again? I have 3 tables

```
Product Table
id
product_name


Productquantity Table
id
item_id
price

Orders
id
req_id
quantity_id
quantity
amount
```

How can I get the product name in my CartView? I only have this in my code

Order Model

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Productquantity', 'item_id', 'id');
    }
```

My Controller

```
 $dataReqorder = Reqorder::where('req_id','=', $shoppingId)->with('product')->get();
```

My View

```
@foreach($dataReqorder as $order)
<tr class="item{{$order->id}}">
<td> <a href="products/{{$order->id}}" class="name">{{$order->product->prod_id}}</a> </td>
<td>{{$order->amount}}</td>
<td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I want this {{$order->product->prod_id}} should be the name of the product instead of the product ID.. I just do not know how to do it on model and controller.. Please help

Comment: you don't have `item_id` field into `orders` table.  
And Maybe you must change `belongsTO` for `belongsTo`

Comment: you cant use `belongsTo` because is a belongs to many, I can see that you has a product_quantity table.

Comment: [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: @MaruAmallo  sorry, I forgot to edit, product_id is to item_id. belongsTo is not the main problem as it fetch the data now, want I want is the item name using the quantity_id of Order Table to Product table.

Comment: I get the details quantity_id to the order table and get the item_id(product id) now I do not know how to build a model and controller to display the product name in my view

Comment: the `Reqorder` is `Order` model?

Comment: yes, that is my model

Comment: I make an answer for you. I hope help you.
You need follow standards because your life will be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reorder some things

```
// Reorder tables and models
Table Schema and models

Product Model (Table name => 'products')
id
product_name


OrderProduct (Table name => 'order_product')
id
product_id
order_id
price
quantity_id
quantity

Order Model (Table name => 'orders')
id
req_id
amount

// Product Model
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('price', 'quantity_id','quantity');
}
// Order Model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('price', 'quantity_id','quantity');
}
// Controller
$dataReqorder = Order::where('req_id','=', $shoppingId)->with('products')->get();

// View 
@foreach($dataReqorder as $order)
    <tr class="item{{$order->id}}">
    @foreach($order->products as $product)
        {{$product->id}}<br>
        {{$product->pivot->price}}<br>
        {{$product->pivot->quantity_id}}<br>
        {{$product->pivot->quantity}}<br>
    @endforeach
    <td>{{$order->amount}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

For more info I recommend you to see the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I tried your solution but still not resolving the problem. What I want is to display the Product Name from Product table using the product_id in OrderTable with your design.. the Product name cannot be displayed :(

Comment: Hi, you did a dd()? I cant test or play with the code because I only write the code I has not the project running