# Laravel - Display Array/String Object in view from database

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Data are stored as `["item_1", "item_2"]` in database like shown below.

I want to display those data in view blade properly.

[image: Items Model]

**Product Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'prod_id'];
public function models() {
    return $this->hasMany(Model::class, 'prod_id');
}
```

**Model Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['model', 'prod_id'];
protected $cat = ['model'=>'array'];
public function model()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'prod_id');
}
```

**Controller - store method**

```
public function create (Request $request, Product $product){
$models = new Model;
    {
     $model = json_encode(request('models'));
     $items->models = $model;
     $product->models()->save($models);
    }
}
```

**Controller show method**

```
public function show(request $id){
 $product = Product::findorfail($id);
 $models = Model::with(['model'])->where('prod_id', $product->id)->get();
 return  view ('show',  compact('product', 'models'));
```

**Create View**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Samsung">
<input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Nokia">
<input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Apple">
<button>Add Model</button>
```

I tried show view:

```
@foreach($models as $model)
  {{ json_decode($model->models) }}
@endforeach
```

It throws

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

What am I missing.

PS: MySQL does not support json column, so I saved as text column.

Comment: What is your output of `$models`?

Comment: The controller code you've provided does not make any sense. It appears to be a copy/paste error. Please correct the question.

Comment: @Nawin Its ``{"id":18,"prod_id":22,"models":{"id":22,"user_id":1,```

Comment: @patricus Updated with show method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do someting like this.

**Model Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['models', 'prod_id']; // screenshot says that the field name is "models"

protected $cast = ['models' => 'array']; // the property is $cast no $cat  

public function product()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'prod_id');
}
```

**ModelController - store method**

```
public function store (Request $request){  

  $product = Model::create([
    'models' => json_encode($request->models),
    'prod_id' => $request->prod_id
  ]);  

  return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'created!');
}

public function show(Request $id){

  $model = Model::findOrFail($id)->with('product');

  return  view ('model.show',  compact('model'));
}
```

**ProductController show method**

```
public function show(request $id){
 $product = Product::findOrFail($id)->with('models'); // the method name is findOrFail() no findorfail 
 // $models = Model::with(['model'])->where('prod_id', $product->id)->get();
 return  view ('show',  compact('product'));
}
```

**Into the show View**

```
@foreach($product->models as $models)
  @foreach(json_decode($models->models) as $model)
    {{ $model }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: What should I do to achieve the same for multiple fields? Like ``prod_id``, ``model_name`` to pass through json/array in a single column as done for ``size`` above?

Comment: Look my answer in this link. I think is the answer for your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269528/show-product-name-in-laravel-model-relationship/49269931#49269931.  If not make a new question and i'll try to help you again

Comment: I have 3 fields ``name, address, profile_photo``. Here is new Question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505465/laravel-save-multiple-field-values-in-json-array-in-a-column)

Answer (score 2):

Your **Models** Model confuses me a little bit.  You seem to have a field name `model` that's the same as a relationship method name.  That means whenever you include that relation, it'd functionally override that property with data from the related table.  (I say 'functionally' because you're using dynamic properties, whereas it is actually possible to explicitly tell Eloquent whether you want an attribute or relation without making it guess.)

That said, your `$model->models` property could be coming back as an array for one of two reasons.  The first is that it may be accidentally referring to a relational data-set and not the JSON string you were expecting.  The second is you've corrected the `protected $cat = ['model'=>'array'];` to read `protected $cast = ['models'=>'array'];`, and it's stepping on your toes now.  By casting it to an array, it may be getting automatically get interpreted back into one *before* you call `json_decode` on it.

Either way, I'd `dd($model->models)` to see what it is first.

Comment: ``dd($models->models)`` show an array of models ``Collection {#209 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => "["Samsung","Nokia","Apple"]"
  ]
}`` . Nested ``foreach` loops solved.

Comment: The collection result of `$models = Model::with(['model'])->where('prod_id', $product->id)->get();`.  That's a many-to-one relationship though, right?  Replace `get` with `first`.

Comment: ``Property [models] does not exist on this collection instance.``

Comment: My bad, I think you had it right the first time with nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your foreach like this:

```
@foreach($models->models as $model)
  {{ json_decode($model) }}
@endforeach
```

because Your array is like this

```
{"id":18,"prod_id":22,"models":{"id":22,"user_id":1}}
```

In here the `$models` is getting only `id` and `prod_id` `models` is still array so your foreach should be `@foreach($models->models as $model)`

Sample Code is here:

```
$arr = '{"id":18,"prod_id":22,"models":{"id":22,"user_id":1}}';
echo '<pre>';
foreach (json_decode($arr->models) as $str){
    echo $str;
}
```